# Saving Apple Receipts to database; limiting 1 receipt to 1 user

Tags: ios, mysql, in-app-subscription

So I'm developing an app for my service. It is subscription based. I already handle web based subscriptions via Stripe but for iOS apps they need to go through apple's in-app subscriptions.

The only way I can see to reliably do this is to send the receipt of the subscription to my server, then my server confirm it's validity with apple. It also needs to check it's validity even if it's on the web version. So I'm looking at saving the apple receipt in my database to check it's status each time a user logs in.

The Apple receipt is quite large (my test one is 7300 bytes) so I'll be storing it in a `MEDIUMTEXT` MySQL field. I'd like to set `UNIQUE` on that field but it's just too large to set that.

So I'm trying to figure out how to ensure that one apple receipt/account can only be used with 1 of my service accounts.

Does anybody know any ways of doing this?

(sorry in advance if my question is unclear or if this is a typical iOS question, please let me know and I'll try to make the question clearer and more concise)

Comment: Can you clarify "I'm trying to figure out how to ensure that one apple receipt/account can only be used with 1 of my service accounts."? This is the standard way all AppStore app purchases work.

Comment: @l'L'l in my database for me to give the user premium status I need to link it in the database. When it sends the receipt it sends both user_id & appleReceipt but they could potentially use the same receipt for multiple users. So I’m trying to prevent this

Comment: You can store the original transaction ID and make sure it is only associated with one login.

Comment: @Paulw11 Perfect, this is what I was looking for, could you put this in answer form so I can accept it?